# Tellraw command with hoverEvent show_achievement 1.14

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, I've been searching the web for a way to get the tellraw command with a hover event of show_achievement. I've tried this command:

```
/tellraw @p {"text":"Hover","hoverEvent":{"action":"show_achievement","value":"achievement.stoneAge"}}
```

I'm confused, am I spelling something wrong? Should it be achievement and not advancement? I've tried generators, I've tried help pages, and nothing is working. Please help.

Edit: Is it the achievement. prefix? I am so confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`show_achievement` simply doesn't exist. The only possibilities are `show_text`, `show_item` and `show_entity`. Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Raw_JSON_text ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Commands&oldid=1409433#Raw_JSON_text))